# how does SEH based exploit bypass DEP and ASLR?

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit, seh, dep

I am new in SEH based exploit

Why didn't we put our return address directly in SE handler to jump to our shellcode? (with no safeSEH)

can't any body explain the reason of using pop pop ret?

I read something that said SEH bypass ASLR and DEP, but how?

our shellcode finally will be located in stack and stack will be still nonexecutable, how DEP is bypassed?

Comment: Consider rewording your problem or breaking it up into separate questions so you can get a better quality answer.

Comment: Also, you may want to cite the sources that provide some of this information, in case there are other interpretations of the source.

Comment: also, as this is not code, you might consider http://security.stackexchange.com/